# Can't open Delphi projects directly from the file explorer

Tags: delphi

When I click on a Delphi project file in Windows' File Explorer, it won't open in Delphi like normal. I have to first open Delphi and then choose the file I want to open from there. Has anybody had this problem, or is it maybe a problem with Windows 11?

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What version of Delphi did you install?

Comment: I think you should have the file set to open with bds.exe, not bdslauncher.exe.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Delphi 10.3

Comment: @PhilipJ.Rayment Could you please explain how to do that?

Comment: You should enable showing file endings in the explorer settings

Comment: @DelphiCoder I tried it, but it did not help.

Comment: bdslauncher is the correct association. It looks like you have perhaps installed or uninstalled different versions. Try a fresh start with full uninstall and then reinstall. Alternatively if you have a repair option in the programs control panel then give that a try.

Comment: From the screenshots it looks like .dfm files are associated with a very old Delphi version (Delphi 7?) Maybe that is somehow related the problem. But I have no idea how to fix it if the usual way of selecting BdsLauncher in the Windows Open With dialog does not work.

Comment: My comment was intended to help you choosing the correct file to open. Also it might help you later when working with files, you immediately see the extension and have not to guess based on the file icon (if one is present) or first have to mark it to see the extension somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set File association in Delphi options dialog under `Tools > Options > IDE > File Association`

[image: Delphi Options File Association]

Note you may need to launch Delphi with administrative privileges for it to be able to change the default file associations in Windows.

Another way is to go and double click on the file and then in the shown window chose `More Apps` to shown window with more listed apps and more importantly with the check mark option to always use the chosen app for opening of this file type.

Comment: I didn't realized there was an answer posted in the meantime when I closed as a dupe. If you delete answer here and post it under duplicate question I will delete mine there as there is no need to have two similar answers.

Comment: I don't know if this answer would fit into the Duplicate question. In the said question OP was asking about Delphi 2007. I'm not sure Delphi 2007 already allowed setting file association through the IDE. Especially after reading Ian Boyd answer which is suggesting the use of Repair option in Add/Remove Programs on control panel. This would indicate that Delphi 2007 set its file associations with its installer and not from its IDE. So unless you can verify that Delphi 2007 IDE does offer ability to set specific file type associations from within the IDE my answer doesn't truly fit there.

Comment: Duplicate question asks how to fix associations without reinstalling the IDE. The fact it covers older version, does not mean that this answer does not fit there regardless of the version. Just put the version (lowest you know supports Options dialog in the answer to distinguish it). It is better to have that information concentrated on single question than spread across multiple ones. Since the answer is accepted, you cannot move it, so my suggestion is not relevant anymore.